# How can I avoid 'are the same file' error when using 'ln' in Linux?

Tags: linux, ln

I'm trying to link a directory to another location. Using the following command

```
ln -sf . dot
```

succeeds the first time, but it returns an error the second time:

```
ln -sf . dot
```

Output:

> ln: '.' and 'dot/.' are the same file

This was on [Ubuntu 16.04.12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus).

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: `[[ -L $thedir ]] || ln -sf . $thedir` maybe?

Comment: @g00se That's a good idea to use the shell somehow, assuming there's no single command that does it all. But I'd want `/bin/sh` then, so it works in a Makefile. I'm not sure if `/bin/sh` is bash. What shell are you using? For me, `[ -L dot ] || ln -sf . dot` seems to work in bash.

Comment: `How to avoid this error?` Do not run it twice. I do not understand the question. What behavior do you _want_? To "avoid", don't do it.

Comment: @g00se Actually I don't want to skip overwriting the link just because it exists already. Because it may already exist with a different target.

Comment: @KamilCuk. I want `ln -sf` to behave in the documented way, where it creates a symlink to the target. The point of `-f` is to overwrite the target if it already exists, and this is documented as well. (Technically we can get the error without running the command twice; the error only requires that the link already exists, and it could have been created by some other tool like `rsync`. Nonetheless the simplest example involves running the command twice, so I'll leave the question in those terms.)

Comment: I got a different error message: `ln: dot/.: cannot overwrite directory` on my Ubuntu. Which distribution of Linux are you using ?

Comment: @Philippe I am using Ubuntu 16.04.12.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427996/3966456).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ln -n` to not dereference the existing [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). See [`man ln`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln).

```
ln -nsf . dot
```

Comment: By the way, I had read the manpage, but didn't understand what it meant by "treat  LINK_NAME as a normal file if it is a symbolic link to a directory". Apparently what this means is that `ln` tries to follow the destination link unless you tell it not to. (Which is surprising, given that the purpose of `-f` is to *overwrite* the destination, and it's perfectly happy not following it if it points to a file. But it makes sense now that I see that `ln` actually does different things depending on whether the target is a directory or file.)